# SPARQL to get highest mountains from dbpedia

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

Howto get a list of the top 10 highest mountains from dbpedia ?

I don't know howto start, because I already fail by looking for the correct properties of a specific mountain.
I can't find any property of 'elevation' or 'altitude' in
http://dbpedia.org/page/Mount_Everest

I thought that an interesting property would be the elevation ?

Can someone help ?

Comment: Try Wikidata instead: [4 examples](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service/queries/examples#Mountains).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem with publicly curated data, there's no formal schema, so some of the mountains have dbo:elevation (http://dbpedia.org/page/Lhotse) and some only have dbp:elevationRef (http://dbpedia.org/page/K2). You have two options, one technical, one socially beneficial.

Technical option would be a query to get the top 14 and use post processing on the string "(Ranking x)" to get the top 10.

`SELECT DISTINCT ?mountain ?rank 
WHERE {
    ?mountain dbp:listing dbr:Eight-thousander.
    ?mountain dbp:elevationRef ?rank.
}`

Socially beneficial solution is to go through those mountains in the Eight-thousander category on Wikipedia and make sure they all have the elevation property set in their description boxes so that DBpedia will scrape it and you can run the query you want:

`SELECT DISTINCT ?mountain ?elevation 
WHERE {
    ?mountain dbp:listing dbr:Eight-thousander.
    ?mountain dbo:elevation ?elevation.
} 
ORDER BY DESC(?elevation)
LIMIT 10`